# How can i make the caption of an image italic in Plone

Tags: plone

how can i make the caption of an image italic in python

I want the caption in italic form automatically when i enter the caption in caption field

My code is:-

```
  atapi.TextField('image_caption_text',
              storage = atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
              widget = atapi.RichWidget(
                        description = '',
                        label = _(u'label_image_caption', 
                            default=u'Image Caption'),
                        rows = 5),
              schemata='General',
    ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the caption is rendered later as HTML: use CSS to style the image caption.